# how to shown an element only when another element has a certain change in class

Tags: javascript, html

I have three buttons

```
<button type="button" id="btn-Low" class="btn btn-success disabled">Green</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-Medium" class="btn btn-warning disabled">Orange</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-High" class="btn btn-danger disabled"></button>
```

I want to show an image for each of them if disabled get removed from there class.
Here are the images:

```
<img src="assets/media/logos/red.jpg" id="red" style="width: 250px; height: 250px; display: none" alt="" />
<img src="assets/media/logos/green.jpg" id="green" style="width: 250px; height: 250px; display: none" alt="" />
<img src="assets/media/logos/orange.jpg" id="orange" style="width: 250px; height: 250px; display: none" alt="" />
```

Here is what i tried:

```
<script>
  var delta = document.getElementById("red");
  if (document.getElementById('btn-High').disabled === false;) {
    delta.style.display = "block";
} else {
delta.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
  var omega = document.getElementById("green");
  if (document.getElementById('btn-Low').disabled === false;) {
    omega.style.display = "block";
} else {
omega.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
  var alpha = document.getElementById("orange");
  if (document.getElementById('btn-Medium').disabled === false;) {
    alpha.style.display = "block";
} else {
alpha.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:
Add the image you want to show inside of the button:

```
<button class="btn disabled">
   <img src="..." />
   Color
</button>
```

Then add some CSS to hide the image when the button has a class of `.disabled`:

```
.btn.disabled > img {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why cant it be?=

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery hasClass, for the event use the same when the disabled class is removed.

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
if (! $( "#btn-Low" ).hasClass( "disabled" )){
  $( "#red" ).show();
}
```